# laravel calculo edad

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Ayuda necesito calcular la edad, tengo la fecha de nacimiento pero no me resulta la funcion, esto es lo que tengo

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="fecha_nacimiento">Fecha Nacimiento</label>
     <p>{{ $alumno->fecha_nacimiento}}</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="edad">Edad</label>
     <p>{{ Carbon::createFromDate($alumno->fecha_nacimiento)}}</p>
    </div>
   </div>
```

intente con carbon pero no me da el resultado, me arroja error, alguien sabe como se usa esa funcion createFromDate??

Comment: ¿qué es lo que no funciona? ¿cuál es la función que no da el resultado? ¿cuál es el error?

Comment: Quiero mostrar la edad a partir de la fecha d nacimiento almacenada en una vista, pero coloco {{ Carbon::createFromDate($alumno->fecha_nacimiento)}} y me lanza error: Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
Trailing data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asumiendo que la fecha que tienes almacenada en `$alumno->fecha_nacimiento` esté expresada en algún formato válido, tal como 1990-10-25, utilizando el método parse para convertir la fecha y con la propiedad age, deberías obtener lo que buscas (en años):

```
$edad = Carbon::parse($alumno->fecha_nacimiento)->age; // 1990-10-25
dump($edad) // 26
```

---

Tal y como lo indica la documentación de Carbon, si deseas utilizar el método createFromDate() deberás escribir cada componente de la fecha separado por coma:

```
Carbon::createFromDate(1990, 10, 25)->age;
```

Comment: Gracias maestro!